# How to execute a bash script on multiple directories?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a `conv.sh` script that loops over MP3 files in the current directory and converts them into OGG. I have also several directories {F1, F2,..., F20} at `/path/to/Files/`. How should I execute `conv.sh` on all of these directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```sh
curdir=$(pwd)
for folder in /path/to/Files/*; do 
  [ -d "$folder" ] && cd "$folder" && ./conv.sh
done
cd $curdir
```

Or assuming you are at `/path/to/Files/`, this also works

```
for f in *; do [ -d "$f" ] && cd "$f" && ./conv.sh; done; cd ..
```

You could use `F{1..20}` instead of `*` for more precision.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get: 'bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: Woops, my bad, it's corrected now. There was an unneeded `;`

Comment: Just needed replace '&& ./conv.sh' with of '&& bash /path/to/conv.sh'. Otherwise work as intended. Thanks

Comment: Either solution will break if your current working directory contains whitespace, you need to quote inside `[`, or use `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
./conv.sh /path/to/Files/F[0-9]*/*.mp3
```

This command treat only mp3 in dirs beginning with `F` and a number using [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Answer (score 1):

You can use xargs or GNU parallel:

```
echo /path/to/Files/F{1..20} | tr ' ' '\n' |
  xargs -L conv.sh
```

or:

```
echo /path/to/Files/F{1..20} | tr ' ' '\n' |
  parallel conv.sh
```

#### Edit - handle space sensibly

As noted by Ole, none of the above methods handle space properly, i.e. `dir name` would be considered as two separate arguments, the same problem occurs if the directory name contains newlines.

The best way to handle these issues is to use null as delimiter, e.g. with GNU find:

```
find /path/to/Files -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/F[0-9]*' -print0 |
  parallel -0 conv.sh
```

Comment: This works with files containing space: parallel conv.sh ::: /path/to/Files/F{1..20}